# Wake up WiFi in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an `IntentService` which is called by a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` which is woken by the `AlarmManager` every 8 hours.

So its `AlarmManager` -> `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` -> `IntentService`.

The `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` gets a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` as soon as it starts.

Problem is that the wifi goes to sleep between runs of the `IntentService` and the `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` doesnt seem to wake it up.

I know the wifi also has a wake lock but grabbing it doesnt seem to wake the wifi so how can I wake it? (and obviously then I can take a lock to make sure it wont go to sleep again).

Comment: latest versions of Android (Marshmallow, N), are not so happy with recurrent stuff like the one you're trying. Said that, I recommend checking it out the JobScheduler (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) introduced in API 21 and it's `compat` version that is available on the Google Play Services (it's called Network something, I don't remember)

Comment: Interesting, what would you suggest then if I do need something that runs periodically?

Comment: sorry. I hit enter by accident and didn't fully finished my message. I edited it now... please take a look

Comment: I found the compat version from Google Play, it's called GCM network manager. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager  on both those you can specifically specify that you want the Job to be fired when connection is available.

Comment: Thank you very much! though API 21 it a bit too new and most people are still at KitKat....

Comment: check the GCM Network Manager They both do the same thing, but the GCM Network Manager is compatible I guess all the way back to gingerbread

Comment: It seems the JobScheduler doesnt help me with my network problem